# drawing out objects from an array

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, subclass

Sorry for asking a question again guys, but im stumped yet again, Arraylists just dont like me ;).
Now im stuck with the problem of drawing out the objects, they wont be drawn except for maybe one in a random place. I think that maybe im only creating one object and just placing it in the new array spot but im not totally sure. block is a superclass to dirt.

```
    public class MuthaLoad extends JPanel {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame window = new JFrame("MuthaLoad");
            window.setContentPane(new MuthaLoad());
            window.setSize(600,600);
            window.setLocation(100,100);
            window.setVisible(true);

    }
        private int health=100;
        private int money=100;

        private ArrayList<Block> blockWorld=new ArrayList<Block>();
        private int colum=0;
        private int row=0;

        public MuthaLoad(){
            for(int i=0;i<144;i++){
                if(i%12==0){
                    colum=0;
                    row+=50;
                }
                blockWorld.add(new Block(0,0));
                int random=(int)(Math.random()*100);
                System.out.println(colum + "" + row);
                blockWorld.add(new Block.Dirt(colum,row));
                if(i<72){

                }
                else{
                    blockWorld.add(new Block.Dirt(i,i));
                }
//              else if(random<5){
//                  
//              }
//              else if(random<50){
////                    blockWorld.add(block.new dirt(50,0));
//              }
                colum+=50;
            }
        }
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                for(int i=0;i<144;i++){
                    blockWorld.get(i).draw(g);
                }


        }

}
```

Comment: are you setting the positions of your blocks to different locations?

Comment: yes, they are each getting different x, and y cordinates, but it seems its only creating one, i think its just replacing the last one over and over

Comment: but i dont know how to fix that

Comment: What makes you think it's just replacing the last one over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user and I discussed the problem offline.  We found the issue: in the "Block" class, the variables "x" and "y" were declared static.
As a result, the last assignment done to any Block's "x" and "y" variables was setting the position of all Block objects.